# Node keeps throwing updater: COMPILATION ERROR

Tags: node, baker

Not sure what happened, but every block it throws this at the end of the block. It seems to still be able to endorse and bake though.

`updater: COMPILATION ERROR`

Running on  `006-PsCARTHA`

Answer (score 0):

In general, information about tezos-updater is available in "the datadir of your node" (by default `~/.tezos-node/`), in the `protocol/` folder. There should especially be a file `${DATADIR}/protocol/${ProtoHash}/LOG` that gives details about the error.

In your particular case, the crucial question is which version of `tezos-node` is running (accessible via `tezos-node --version`). I suspect that:

- your node tries to run the "test chain" of 0007-PsDELPHI as we are currently in that voting period
- you are using a version older than v7.0 which is indeed not able to compile this protocol

Comment: I see the same error as @Kevyn, running v7.3.

Comment: What's in the `LOG` file then ?

Comment: I can't find the log file, actually I never saw any "protocol" folder inside .tezos-node

Comment: Actually if I read the source code correctl,y the error message is `src/lib_protocol_updater/updater.ml:78:      log_error "COMPILATION ERROR (%s)" log_file ;` so the log file should be what is in parenthesis exactly after COMPILATION ERROR! :-)

Comment: I'm sorry, I was wrong. The complete log error is `updater: COMPILATION ERROR (/var/run/tezos/node/data/protocol/PsDELPH1Kxsx/LOG)`. LOG file contains: 

```sh: as: not found
File "/tmp/tezos-protocol-build-F3D517/functor.ml", line 1:
Error: I/O error: as  -o '/tmp/tezos-protocol-build-F3D517/functor.o' '/tmp/camlasm66c25c.s'```

Comment: That's useful! It shows that `tezos-node` needs `as`to be in the path in order to be able to compile new economic protocols. How did you get the binaries? Are you using the docker images from the docker hub? Maybe this question with this information should be turned into a issue on the tezos/tezos gitlab.com repository.

Comment: Opened a Gitlab issue: https://gitlab.com/tezos/tezos/-/issues/956